# Конвертировать DOC(s) в PDF в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, doc, конвертер

Возник такой вопрос.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью каких библиотек можно конвертировать документ формата DOC(s) в PDF документ, используя JavaScript?

Без использования серверной части. Спасибо!

Comment: Хмм, интересный вопрос учитывая то что JS не имеет доступа к файловой системе.

Comment: Загружается doc файл средствами FileReader.
---
Скачивается pdf файл средствами FileSaver.js

Comment: Угу, а посередине вам нужен MS Office или OpenOffice. Только в браузере они не работают.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Тоесть получается, что только на стороне сервера такое можно сделать?

И как тогда работают jsPDF, DOCS.js ->> https://github.com/MrRio

Comment: Сгенерировать PDF не очень сложно. Сложно правильно прочитать и разобрать doc(x)